# Viewing tables of data in R

Tags: r

I've mostly used head(), tail(), and View() to look at tables in R, but I wonder if anyone uses anything more sophisticated. I recall reading that there were R <-> Excel interfaces available (based on COM or XLLoop?) - does anyone use one to use Excel (or OpenOffice) to display data frames during an R session, and not necessarily just result the final result exported to a csv file?

**Edit:** Thanks for all the suggestions. I guess I should have specified that I was running Emacs+ESS on a Mac primarily (which disqualifies COM and Deducer), though I also switch to Linux and Windows on occasion. I guess View() still is the best multi-platform solution that I could find...

Comment: ... View() and data.entry() just blew my mind.  I don't know how I've never seen them before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, I sometimes use Excel to view data from R during a session.  I recommend looking at [this blog post on the Learning R blog](http://learnr.wordpress.com/2009/10/06/export-data-frames-to-multi-worksheet-excel-file/).  I use the RDCOMClient; it allows for more than just export/import, but the trade-off is added complexity.

*Edit:* There are several other solutions that are non-COM based in that blog post, including using ODBC.

Comment: Oops, forgot COM was a Windows thing (which I recently moved from - come to think of it, I *had* played around with RDCOM a long while back). But the blog post was very helpful.

Answer (score 10):

You can use the basic data editor to view the data

```
edit(your.data.frame)
```

Comment: Thanks - I'm familiar with this one, but isn't it inferior to View()? It's similar except that it waits for you to close the window to proceed (and it's better to call `invisible(edit(my.data.frame))`).

Comment: @crippledlambda -- `edit()` allows you to edit data, with something like `temp <- edit(temp)`. It uses your default editor, but I think it forces the built-in editor for data frames. For more sophisticated data frame editing there's `tk2edit()` in the tcltk2 package.

Answer (score 4):

Another elegant option would be to use the [DT](https://github.com/rstudio/DT) package

```
if (!require("DT")) devtools::install_github("rstudio/DT")

datatable(iris)
```

This will open a paginated, sortable and filterable table in your browser.
See http://rstudio.github.io/DT/ for examples.

Comment: whoa, that is cool. had to install devtools first but got it working and looks like something I could use.

Answer (score 4):

You can run `utils::View(data)`.

Another option would be to open a new RStudio window. One can do this (on linux at least) simply by running in the terminal : rstudio
If one wants to be able to close the terminal afterwards, just run

```
nohup rstudio &
```

Answer (score 3):

I use the following function to look at a sample of lines from a dataframe... I keep it in my startup and use it all the time to run checks... frequently I'll run this a couple of times...

```
#
# sample a couple of lines from a data frame
#
sample.df <- function(df, n=3, ordered=TRUE) {
    if(ordered) {
            df[sort(sample(nrow(df), min(nrow(df), n))),]
    } else {
            df[sample(nrow(df), min(nrow(df), n)),]
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, strangely, I had also made `sample()` a generic function and added a method for data frames in my `.Rprofile`! But only marginally better than head() and tail()...

Comment: The advantage of using sample.df() rather than head() or tail() is that there is frequently an ordering to the data.frame you aren't initially aware of, so I'd often use all three!

Answer (score 2):

Deducer's [Data Viewer](http://www.deducer.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php?n=Main.DeducerManual).

Form the manual:

> The data viewer can be accessed using either deducer("Data viewer") or the data.viewer() function

There are many other useful features there, all of them available from command interface.

Comment: Oh, I wanted this be the solution so badly, but on a Mac it looks like I need to run it through JGR... I'm an Emacs geek.

Comment: @Stephen, It works happily with emacs and even terminal. The only thing you don't have menus. This is why the data.viewer() function. I am already planing for a while to write a menu interface to deducer for emacs. Never got down to it. Hopefully by the end of this year;)

Comment: Oh crack, I see it now. It does not work under Mac, sorry didn't know that.

Answer (score 1):

`fix` works for me

also `my.df[seq(1, nrow(my.df), nrow(my.df)/30),]`

Comment: thanks but also like edit.data.frame() I think, and View is superior for viewing data, if I'm not mistaken (you can accidentally modify values in the table with fix, and it used to convert variable classes/modes if I'm not mistaken).

Answer (score 1):

As `edit` is too basic, I tend to just open tables in Excel while using R. To do so I write the data to a temporary file, and open it with Excel:

```
open_in_excel <- function(some_df){
    tFile<-tempfile(fileext=paste0(substitute(some_df), ".tsv"),tmpdir="~/tmp")
    write.table(some_df, tFile, row.names=F, sep="\t", quote=F)
    system(paste('open -a \"/Applications//Microsoft Office 2011/Microsoft Excel.app\"', tFile))
}

open_in_excel(iris)
```

For sure the `system` call needs to be adjusted to the used OS and the installation path of Excel.